# Best collection to store two data types?

Tags: java, collections

I was wondering how to store an object and store the order an object was added to an array list for example but any collection would do.

Using the index wont work as I'll be sorting the array list but still wanting to keep track of the order they were added in.

Currently I'm using two array lists, one to store the objects in added order and one to store the objects in sorted order but I feel like this in inefficient.

Comment: If you wrote the object class yourself, initialize some order in the constructor. If you didn't write it, you could extend that object in a new class that you write and do the same.

Comment: How about a `List<Pair<Integer, YourObject>>` sorted by your object, and having the insertion order in the int value?

Comment: What would you be using this index for? If it is second factor for sorting you can use whichever stable sorting algorithm you feel like. If it will have any additional impact of your logic, share what it will be so that we can try to help.

Comment: @ernest_k This would be perfect in theory, I'll have a look thanks

Comment: @BorisStrandjev the index is just to store the order the object was added to the collection, but has no use for the object itself. The only reason I want to store the order it was added is so when the collection is sorted I still know which object was added to the collection first, second etc.

Comment: Your current solution seems pretty good. Can you expand on what problems you have with it?

Comment: @MikeFHay I don't have any issues, was just wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial answer most people will give you is `HashMap`, but in this case it would be abusing the data structure. Second guess would be a List> but while it would be not abusing the structure, it's still not properly OO code.

Since your object and the inserting order belong together, the right approach would be to create a new class, containing your object and the inserting order position and add instances of this class to any collection you like.

Comment: The object doesn't care about what position it is in, just another class using it does. I'll look into list to see if it will work, thanks!

Comment: So this other class cares about the combination... That's *the* reason to create a composition of these two.

Answer (score 0):

U can use your own implementation of a LinkedList. Create a class with the attributes that you want to store.

Here's a sample code to implement a custom LinkedList.

```
public class FooLinkedList {
    String itemName; // anything you want to store
    FooLinkedList next;

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public FooLinkedList(String itemName, FooLinkedList next) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```